# Imp code modification required

Tags: java, jdbc

Following code needs modification can we use constants files if yes then how we can segregate string in separate files so that loop continues then performance is not impacted

```
for (int j = 0; j < subconfigListRLC.size(); j++) {
    StringBuffer sqlQuery = new StringBuffer();
    test = (SubConfigurationDetailsObject) subconfigListRLC.get(j);
    if (test.getFlag().equalsIgnoreCase("T")) {
        sqlQuery = sqlQuery.append("update SUB_CONFIG set TSTED = " 
                + test.getSubConfigurationIndexNo() + " , Q_SUB_INDX = 0 "
                + "where BASE_ENG_KEY = '" + test.getBaseEngineKey() + "' "
                + "AND MODEL_YEAR = '" + modelYear + "' "
                + "AND RLHP_LVW = '" + test.getRoadLoadHorsepowerValue() + "' "
                + "AND LVW_TEST_WT_WO_CONT = '" + test.getEtwValue() + "' "
                + "AND INERTIA_WT_CLASS = '" + test.getInertiaWeightClassNo() + "' "
                + "AND TEST_GROUP_ID = " + test.getTestGroupId() + " "
                + "AND ENGINE_CODE = '" + test.getEngineCode() + "' "
                + "AND AXLE_RATIO = '" + test.getAxleRatioValue() + "'");
    } else if (test.getFlag().equalsIgnoreCase("U")) {
        sqlQuery = sqlQuery.append("update SUB_CONFIG set Q_SUB_INDX = " 
                + test.getSubConfigurationIndexNo() + " "
                + "where BASE_ENG_KEY = '" + test.getBaseEngineKey() + "' "
                + "AND MODEL_YEAR = '" + modelYear + "' "
                + "AND RLHP_LVW = '" + test.getRoadLoadHorsepowerValue() + "' "
                + "AND LVW_TEST_WT_WO_CONT = '" + test.getEtwValue() + "' "
                + "AND INERTIA_WT_CLASS = '" + test.getInertiaWeightClassNo() + "' "
                + "AND TEST_GROUP_ID = " + test.getTestGroupId() + " "
                + "AND ENGINE_CODE = '" + test.getEngineCode() + "' "
                + "AND AXLE_RATIO = '" + test.getAxleRatioValue() + "'");
    }
    //System.out.println("Query----------->"+sqlQuery.toString());
    processor.getUpdateAccessor().executeUpdateSql(sqlQuery.toString());
}
```

Comment: The first modification that that code needs is to use parameterized SQL. That will allow you to put the SQL in text files - but *far* more importantly, it will help avoid SQL injection attacks and conversion errors.

Comment: in the spirit of Jon Skeet's comment: http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: @jon Skeet how can i implement the same.

Comment: click the link above and follow the instructions in the "Java" section

Comment: Please don't forget to add a '?' to questions!  Some people do a search in the page for '?' and if none exists in the 'question' go directly to the next (actual) question in line.

Comment: can any body tell me what will give better perfomance out of a and b options        a) for(int i=0;i<configIndexNumber.size();i++){String Key = oldIndex.getVehConfigNo()+oldIndex.getBaseEngineKey()
if(!configIdxNnb.containsKey(Key))         {     newConfigIndexList.add(oldIndex);
 }   
  }
b)String Key=null; for(int i=0;i<configIndexNumber.size();i++){ConfigurationDetailsObject oldIndex =(ConfigurationDetailsObject)configIndexNumber.get(i);
 key = oldIndex.getVehConfigNo()+oldIndex.getBaseEngineKey()
        if(!configIdxNnb.containsKey(Key )---            }

Comment: @Shree: It's a really bad idea to include blocks of code within comments, and comments aren't the right place to ask questions, either. This seems entirely unrelated to your original question, so you should make a new post.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Java `PreparedStatement` in order to build the query. You can then store the query string for the `PreparedStatement` in a properties file. Read the two possible query strings into variables before entering the loop (in fact you may want to build both PreparedStatements before entering the loop - depending on whether you always use them both). You can then call `clearParamaters`, then set your new parameters, execute, repeat.

Answer (score 1):

As you asked for the exact details, something like this. Search for javadocs on `PreparedStatement`. Javadocs are always worth reading.

```
String sql = "update SUB_CONFIG set TSTED = ? , Q_SUB_INDX = ? " +
    "where BASE_ENG_KEY = ? " +
    "AND MODEL_YEAR = ? " +
    "AND RLHP_LVW = ? " +
    "AND LVW_TEST_WT_WO_CONT = ? " +
    "AND INERTIA_WT_CLASS = ? " +
    "AND TEST_GROUP_ID = ? " +
    "AND ENGINE_CODE = ? " +
    "AND AXLE_RATIO = ?");
PreparedStatement statement = connection.createPreparedStatement(sql);
for (SubConfigurationDetailsObject test: subconfigListRLC) {
    if (test.getFlag().equalsIgnoreCase("T")) {
        statement.setIntParam(1, test.getSubConfigurationIndexNo());
        statement.setIntParam(2, 0);
    } else if (test.getFlag().equalsIgnoreCase("U")) {
        statement.setIntParam(1, 0);
        statement.setIntParam(2, test.getSubConfigurationIndexNo());
    } else {
        continue;
    }
    statement.set...Param(3, ...);
    ...
    statement.executeUpdate();
 }
```

You may probably only need one PreparedStatement, and the result is indeed faster.
BTW. better use StringBuilder instead of StringBuffer.